# experimental sequence of number

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I'm doing a small numerical experiment. I got, from the first simulations, the following sequence of numbers. I'm trying to imagine a mathematical law behind this sequence. It could be a geometric progression?

1.333333333

1.75

2.491107286

3.835656425

6.219456109

10.44686695

17.99815841

31.6031634

56.31814911

101.5516622
...

Comment: Since $$\frac{2.4911...}{1.75}\neq\frac{1.75}{1.3333333...}$$ the sequence cannot be a geometric one.

Comment: It is likely that the sequence grows geometrically. Perhaps you could share in which context you got these values, what is your experiment exactly?

Comment: You're giving no error bounds -- does that mean you trust all the significant digits you quote?

Comment: The ratios between successive terms are roughly constant, but they do increase monotonically… so there looks to be a super-exponential trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like a simple exponential growth. To a rough approximation:

```
 y = A*exp(x/t) + y0

 y0 0.95321
 A  0.26613
 t  1.68515
```

...which makes it a geometric progression with an added constant term.